# Password Reset link redirecting to Explain Domain page

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

[Reset password is redirecting me to this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRW4V.png)

But I also I am using .org domain. So if that problem is with this domain so what should I do?

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#language-code
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#site-id
SITE_ID = 1
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-i18n
USE_I18N = True
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-l10n
USE_L10N = True
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-tz
USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: In order to receive help, edit your question, add, for example, the code of the view that generates that email.

Comment: @Evhz there is no code for Password reset in views it is a default functionality sir...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `django.contrib.sites` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` the password reset link will get generated using the [default sites object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework). You should be able to edit it in the "Sites" section in your admin.